# Move li text but not list type image

Tags: html, css

How can I possibly align the the `li` text vertically with the 'list circle'.
I can't move the text up a little without moving the circles too.
Is there CSS style that works only on `li` text?

Expected end result
[image]

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl',function(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.disableSave = true
})
```

```css
.password-strength {
  list-style: none;
}

.password-strength > li:before {
  font-family: Ionicons !important;
  content: '\f170';
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.password-strength > li.checked:before {
  font-family: Ionicons !important;
  content: '\f16d';
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #46cb4f;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div controller="mainCtrl as vm" class="top20">
    <password-strength ng-model="vm.model.newPassword"></password-strength>
    <h4>Your password must contain the following:</h4>
    <ul class="password-strength">
      <li ng-class="{'checked': false}">At least 1 uppercase letter</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">At least 1 lowercase letter</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">a number</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">a symbol e.g: $ £ # @</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">and have more than 7 characters</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Use li{font-size: 0;}

Comment: This will affect size of my circles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

  .controller('mainCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.disableSave = true
  })
```

```css
.password-strength {
  list-style: none;
}

.password-strength>li:before {
  font-family: Ionicons !important;
  content: '\f170';
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: -2px;
}

.password-strength>li.checked:before {
  font-family: Ionicons !important;
  content: '\f16d';
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #46cb4f;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div controller="mainCtrl as vm" class="top20">
    <password-strength ng-model="vm.model.newPassword"></password-strength>
    <h4>Your password must contain the following:</h4>
    <ul class="password-strength">
      <li ng-class="{'checked': false}">At least 1 uppercase letter</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">At least 1 lowercase letter</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">a number</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">a symbol e.g: $ £ # @</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">and have more than 7 characters</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Smart, I didn't know you can apply size to vertical-align. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just Added below css in `li:before`

`display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;`

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl',function(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.disableSave = true
})
```

```css
.password-strength {
  list-style: none;
}

.password-strength > li:before {
  font-family: Ionicons !important;
  content: '\f170';
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.password-strength > li.checked:before {
  font-family: Ionicons !important;
  content: '\f16d';
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #46cb4f;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div controller="mainCtrl as vm" class="top20">
    <password-strength ng-model="vm.model.newPassword"></password-strength>
    <h4>Your password must contain the following:</h4>
    <ul class="password-strength">
      <li ng-class="{'checked': false}">At least 1 uppercase letter</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">At least 1 lowercase letter</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">a number</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">a symbol e.g: $ £ # @</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">and have more than 7 characters</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add position and top property to pseudo elements

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl',function(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.disableSave = true
})
```

```css
.password-strength {
  list-style: none;
}

.password-strength > li:before {
  font-family: Ionicons !important;
  content: '\f170';
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

.password-strength > li.checked:before {
  font-family: Ionicons !important;
  content: '\f16d';
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #46cb4f;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div controller="mainCtrl as vm" class="top20">
    <password-strength ng-model="vm.model.newPassword"></password-strength>
    <h4>Your password must contain the following:</h4>
    <ul class="password-strength">
      <li ng-class="{'checked': false}">At least 1 uppercase letter</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">At least 1 lowercase letter</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">a number</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">a symbol e.g: $ £ # @</li>
      <li ng-class="{'checked': true}">and have more than 7 characters</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```